# How to implement auto-increment Id in mongodb using C# driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, auto-increment

I tried to implement this and it's working in MongoDB shell, but how to set property `id` to the value of js stored procedure to be called? Every thing l tried ended up with saving js function name as string in `id` property.

I created custom serializer for `id`:

```
public class MyIdSerializer : SerializerBase<Int64>
        {
            public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, Int64 value)
            {
                if (value == 0)              {
context.Writer.WriteString($"getValueForNextSequence(\"myCollection\")");
                }
                else
                    context.Writer.WriteInt64(value);
            }
        }
```

I only need to set the `id` value if its value is `0` (i.e: inserting new document).

This code will store the function name as string and will not execute it.